# cURL able to make cookie but not use it

Tags: php, bash, curl

I'm trying to script bash to do a few simple curl commands.

I can generate a cookie that I want to use with the following command:

```
curl -c cookie --data "user=user&password=pass" //example/login.php
```

However, when I try passing it into the site again the cookie is ignored. It's as if I didn't even login into the first place. The command I'm using is the following:

```
curl -b cookie //example/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to store the cookie that comes back. You do so by specifying a cookie file:

```
curl -c cookies.txt -d "user=user&password=pass" //example/login.php
```

and to use those cookie in later requests you do:

```
curl -b cookies.txt //example/
```

Comment: my first list of code already saves the cookie just fine. while the second line of code you provided does not work sadly (btw I also do not believe I need to pass over again the user name and password as the cookie I'm using for the site has the authorization already saved from the server that I am the user who previously logged in)

Answer (score 0):

it turns out I wasn't generating my cookie correctly after all.
I was actually missing some additional variables that were required in my POST statement, which interacted with the php log in script I was using.